# How to Install phpunit 3.5 on mac with MAMP

Tags: macos, phpunit, mamp

I'm trying to install PHPUnit 3.5 on Mac OS X with MAMP. I did install PHPUnit 3.5 via PEAR of MAMP. This is all correctly and phpunit is located /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/PEAR/PHPUnit. The executable is located in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/.

But when I want to execute phpunit it doesn't do anything, even when I do execute it in the bin folder of MAMP php.

Can somebody help me with this?

**Update**

which phpunit: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin//phpunit

which pear: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin//pear

pear list
Installed packages, channel pear.php.net:

Package          Version State

Archive_Tar      1.3.7   stable

Console_Getopt   1.2.3   stable

PEAR             1.9.1   stable

Structures_Graph 1.0.3   stable

XML_Util         1.2.1   stable

**Content of phpunit**

```
#!/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php
<?php

require_once 'PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php';
PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::getInstance()->addFileToBlacklist(__FILE__, 'PHPUNIT');

if (extension_loaded('xdebug')) {
    xdebug_disable();
}

if (strpos('/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php', '@php_bin') === 0) {
    set_include_path(dirname(__FILE__) . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
}

require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';

define('PHPUnit_MAIN_METHOD', 'PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main');

PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main();
```

Comment: please put also the content of "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin//phpunit"

Comment: I added the content of phpunit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the output of `which phpunit` and `which pear` and `pear list`?

Also did you install phpunit with the `--alldeps` option?

Comment: Hi added the results to my post. I did indeed used --alldeps

Comment: What do you mean by "not doing anything"? Try just running 'phpunit' wihtout any arguments. Does it output the manual?

Comment: Hmm. I'm stumped then. It's weird that it's recognized by which, but you can actually run it. Did you check your log files to see if any php errors are occuring?

Comment: It can't find require_once 'PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php'; as this is located in Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/PEAR

Comment: Is the PEAR directory included in your include paths in php.ini? If not add it and restart apache. If that doesn't work, you may want to to try explicitly adding the location of the PHPUnit library to your include_path.          (e.g include_path = ".:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/PEAR/PHPUnit" #Or wherever it's located on your machine)

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded in installing PHPUnit with XAMPP on Mac, but it took me some time.

One of the trick was to edit the phpunit script to configure it to use XAMPP (or MAMP) PHP executable, and not the default one on Mac.

Comment: My php executable is symlinked to the one of MAMP. So I'm using the correct one.