# How to install phpunit with MAMP on snow leopard 10.6.7

Tags: php, macos, osx-snow-leopard, phpunit

I've been trying to install phpunit on Mac OS X 10.6.7 with MAMP 1.9.5 with no luck.
It's correctly installed, but when I execute it, it doesn't do anything, no output, nothing.

```
bash-3.2# php -i | grep include_path
include_path => .:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/PEAR/PHPUnit => .:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/PEAR/PHPUnit
bash-3.2# which php
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php
bash-3.2# which phpunit
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/phpunit
bash-3.2# which pear
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/pear
bash-3.2# phpunit
bash-3.2# phpunit --version
bash-3.2# phpunit --help
```

I've tried every proposition from this post [How to Install phpunit 3.5 on mac with MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930703/how-to-install-phpunit-3-5-on-mac-with-mamp) , but nothings seems to work for me.

Here is my phpunit content :

```
#!/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php
<?php
/* PHPUnit
 * 
 */

require_once 'PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php';
PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::getInstance()->addFileToBlacklist(__FILE__, 'PHPUNIT');

if (extension_loaded('xdebug')) {
    xdebug_disable();
}

if (strpos('/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php', '@php_bin') === 0) {
    set_include_path(dirname(__FILE__) . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
}

require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';

define('PHPUnit_MAIN_METHOD', 'PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main');

PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main();
```

Does anyone has an idea of what's going on ?

Thanks you very much.

Comment: There seems to be a very similar question over there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588613/installing-phing-phpunit-on-mamp Maybe you might have any luck with that :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following edorian suggestion, I've been to the other thread and found the solution :
restore the system settings for pear, as I probably messed with user settings. Here is the complete solution if anyone needs it :

I did have a similar issue, thanks to this thread I managed to fix it.
Here is how I did it :
Followed edorian suggestion :

> Reinstalling pear
>
> The only way i found arround that is
>   To reinstall save
>   http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar to
>   disk via 'Save as...' and run php
>   go-pear.phar

Then called `pear config-show` to see this :

```
Configuration (channel pear.php.net):
=====================================
Auto-discover new Channels     auto_discover    <not set>
Default Channel                default_channel  pear.php.net
HTTP Proxy Server Address      http_proxy       <not set>
PEAR server [DEPRECATED]       master_server    pear.php.net
Default Channel Mirror         preferred_mirror pear.php.net
Remote Configuration File      remote_config    <not set>
PEAR executables directory     bin_dir          /Users/mbritto/pear/bin
PEAR documentation directory   doc_dir          /Users/mbritto/pear/docs
PHP extension directory        ext_dir          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions
PEAR directory                 php_dir          /Users/mbritto/pear/share/pear
PEAR Installer cache directory cache_dir        /tmp/pear/cache
PEAR configuration file        cfg_dir          /Users/mbritto/pear/cfg
directory
PEAR data directory            data_dir         /Users/mbritto/pear/data
PEAR Installer download        download_dir     /tmp/pear/install
directory
PHP CLI/CGI binary             php_bin          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php
php.ini location               php_ini          /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.3/php.ini
--program-prefix passed to     php_prefix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
--program-suffix passed to     php_suffix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
PEAR Installer temp directory  temp_dir         /tmp/pear/install
PEAR test directory            test_dir         /Users/mbritto/pear/tests
PEAR www files directory       www_dir          /Users/mbritto/pear/www
Cache TimeToLive               cache_ttl        3600
Preferred Package State        preferred_state  stable
Unix file mask                 umask            22
Debug Log Level                verbose          1
PEAR password (for             password         <not set>
maintainers)
Signature Handling Program     sig_bin          /usr/local/bin/gpg
Signature Key Directory        sig_keydir       /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.3/pearkeys
Signature Key Id               sig_keyid        <not set>
Package Signature Type         sig_type         gpg
PEAR username (for             username         <not set>
maintainers)
User Configuration File        Filename         /Users/mbritto/.pearrc
System Configuration File      Filename         /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.3/pear.conf
```

I could see there was two config files one for the system and one for the user (see a the bottom of the config-show.

I backed up my user conf file and replaced it by the system one. Then I needed to set the php_ini setting to /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.3/php.ini (seemed to be absent from the system config file).

After that my phpunit worked again! 
Thanks to everyone :)